# SoapClient XML return string with simpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

So I'm getting an xml file back from a soap service (of which I have no control over). It's returning back an xmlns which is causing simpleXML issues. I'm running a str_replace to get rid of that issue, however now simpleXML just returns an empty object. XML structure appears to be fine, no errors just an empty object.

```
$xmlString = $client->__getLastResponse();
$feed = str_replace(' xmlns="LMSWebservice"', '', $xmlString);
$sData= simplexml_load_string($feed);

print_r($sData);
```

Comment: Are you sure there is only one xmlns tag in the document? If there are more, namepsace collisions might be the problem. Even if there aren't, the xmlns in the original document might be preventing a collision.

Comment: Have you tried telling SimpleXML to ignore errors? `simplexml_load_file($xmlString, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE);`

Comment: benJ thanks, ive tried